# How to overcome CSS calc() function invalid property value, but when typed in inspector same code does work?

Tags: css, sass, gulp, calc

I have the following code in an .scss file:

```
.device_content_div {
    width: calc(100% – 169px);
    margin-left: 204px;
  }
```

It gets processed by Gulp. When I open the relevant page in the Chrome inspector it gets an Invalid Property alert.

[image]

However, when I type the exact same code, manually in the inspector, there is no alert and the code works as it should.

[image]

The same thing goes for Firefox and Safari. I have tried adding it as a  insert in the html page itself, and as an 'unprocessed' plain .css file, but the same thing occurs. I have made sure there are spaces between the operator and the numbers, but to no avail. I'm really stuck here.

How can this happen, and how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first one doesn't look like the minus `-` symbol. It's a bit wider. It's actually an `en dash` symbol not a `minus` symbol. Check here -> https://www.babelstone.co.uk/Unicode/whatisit.html and copy/paste the symbol you use and then write the minus  `-` symbol.

They have different unicodes. 
This `–`  ( the one you use ) is an EN DASH ( you can make it with ALT + 0150 ) and this `-` is a HYPHEN-MINUS {hyphen or minus sign}.

I guess you copy/pasted the code from somewhere and you accidentally inserted an `en dash` instead of the `minus`.

should be `calc(100% - 169px)` iso `calc(100% – 169px)` you can see there's a slight difference in the width of the symbol

See example below

```css
div {
  height:50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 10px 0;
}
div.first {
  /* EN DASH */
  width : calc(100% – 169px);
}

div.second {
  /* minus */
  width : calc(100% - 169px);
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  Not working ( EN DASH )
</div>
<div class="second">
  Working ( minus )
</div>
```

Comment: Very sharp! That was exactly the problem. Replaced the EN DASH with a MINUS and it works like a charm now. Thank you very much :-)